# Link Multiple Gmails iOS Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

How would I go about linking multiple gmail accounts to 1 auth account? I'm currently using Firebase and it seems like it only lets you link 1 account per provider. Is there any other way to do this without Firebase?

Comment: Did you check this out? Looks related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45149324/firebase-verify-multiple-email-addresses-for-the-same-user

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be achieved using Firebase Authentication. 
[Link Multiple Auth Providers to an Account on iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/account-linking)

As the name suggests only multiple Auth providers (Email/Password, PhoneNumber, Facebook, Google, github) can be linked with one another but not with each other.

There can be no linking if the providers are the same.