# Can multiple email credentials be used for one Firebase Auth user?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I need to have a few different login emails for different people to use the same Firebase Auth account. Can I link more than one email credential to an account, or would I need to use a database solution?

I'd be linking about (1-20) emails to each account.

Also, this question was asked here once before in 2017, I am re-asking as there have been large changes since then!

Comment: It uses unique email for each user. You should need a db solution for linking other email credentials. But you can link them. Chek [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45149324/firebase-verify-multiple-email-addresses-for-the-same-user) and [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking) too.

Comment: The first link is the 2017 post I referred to in the question and the second link I already went over ~ it doesn't mention any limits/my question.